# Jquery How to grab an element who does not have a child who contains

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to grab out all the tables who don't have a paragraph child element that contains the word "Figure"

I tried to do it like this:

`$('table :not(:has(p:contains("Figure")))')`

doesn't seem to be returning the tables I need.  Any Idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space after `table`, since you want the `:not` modifier to apply to the tables.

```
$('table:not(:has(p:contains("Figure")))')
```

The way you wrote it, it returns all the descendants that don't have a paragraph containing `Figure`.

Comment: Thanks, That totally makes sense now